# New to php: need to understand password-protecting folder/files

Tags: php, password-protection

Hi I am totally new to php (I literally know nothing about it) but am an intermediate-to-advanced programmer, and need to password protect a folder or otherwise individual files on the server for members to access of a non-profit I run. My server provider just installed php on his server for me (he doesn't have Apache) but told me I have to do all the programming work as he is unfamiliar with it.

1) please recommend any good sources for me to obtain sample scripts and directions on how to implement

2) or please kindly provide step-by-step "guide" on what must be done to protect a folder or file on my server. I want to have either a pop-up window or other means for a limited number of members to enter their chosen username & password.
Most files would be a web page, but some could be downloadable pdf.

Everything I have found here has been little snippets of code, that doesn't explain the Big Pitcure of the php process.

Sorry if my question is confusing to some or not enough info. Thank you for your comments though.

Please understand that I am not the server owner, I am just an individual who has my website on this server space with FTP access to it. I think the guy said it is Microsoft based if that makes sense? and he added php to it for me as I thought that might help, since he doesn't have Apache which would have been the ideal from what I've read.
I don't think that the guy wants to be bothered with adding/removing users & their passwords as members join or leave. the idea is for me to have that control and ability.

If there is some other way besides php ?

@jerrygarciuh 's suggestion seems way more involved than I am capable of implementing! 
;)

Comment: What is "Everything I have found here" ?

Comment: If not Apache, what web server are you running? Usually password-protecting a directory with a set list of users can easily be done by the web server without a dynamic language like PHP.

Comment: Without knowing what your webserver is (iis? apache? nginx? tomcat? etc...), your question cannot be properly answered.

Comment: This question belongs to http://serverfault.com/ not here.

Comment: If you have PHP - but no web server, not sure what you are expecting to accomplish. The easiest way to is give each user their own system account; and put their files in their folder and let the operating system's security frameworks prevent access.

Comment: Everyone is accessing common files not their on individual files. For instance a Member Directory that only members should be able to access & view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem exists that you cannot directly use a PHP script to check a session or anything before loading a pdf.

Quick note is to never depend on obscurity either. So an answer like putting the files into a database and randomly changing them isn't a great idea.

What you need is to prevent them from entering the page, which means the only plausible way to do this is through a configuration file, like web.config (if IIS) or placing a file above the document root . However, we really need more information on this.

Comment: The question states 'doesn't have Apache'

Comment: lol :/ My bad. I got way too anxious.

Answer (score 1):

One method you could use to protect files is to

1) Store the files above document root so no direct http access is possible

2) Authenticate your users and store their status or level of access in their browser session

3) Use a database to store the file names and locations

4) Link to a PHP script which takes the database id of the file and looks up the location and then passes the file to approved users without ever revealing the stored location or indeed the stored file's name.

Here's a little code snippet that shows a file passed in such a manner:

```
if ($bd->file) {    
    $file = "$bd->barge/$bd->file";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $namePartArray = preg_split('/\./', $bd->file);
        $lastIndex = count($namePartArray) - 1;
        $extension = strtolower($namePartArray[$lastIndex]);
        header('Content-type: application/$extension');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$bd->file.'"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
    } else { // if file
        echo "File not found.";
        exit;
    }
} // if file
```